# A word for “useful components”?

Tags: single-word-requests

A word for “useful components”?

Is there a single English noun that means something like “useful small pieces of material or machine elements that the craftsman prefers to have always at hand”? E.g. scraps of cloth, screws, washers, cable ties, or code snippets (for a programmer), or background patterns (for a designer), and so on.

Supposed use cases include: “Don’t forget to bring the needed […] with you” (addressing to a service engineer), “I put all my […] into this folder on Google Drive”.

Comment: We don't use *[the] **needed*** as a noun in such contexts. Mainstream Anglophones might say *Don’t forget to bring the **necessaries***, but it's a little dated/quirky. many speakers of Indian English would quite naturally say *Don’t forget to bring the **needful***, but in general I don't think there's a single word for the target sense. Note that ***the essentials*** would normally carry the strong implication of ***only** the essentials*. Personally, I'd probably say *Don't forget to bring [all] your **paraphernalia**.*

Answer (score 7):

I'm a bit hesitant to put forward [***toolkit***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/toolkit) as it does not really capture things like scraps of cloth. Still, may be of use.

> 1  A set of tools, especially one kept in a bag or box and used for a particular purpose.
>
> 1.1 *Computing* A set of software tools.
>
> 1.2 A personal set of resources, abilities, or skills:
>   *intuition developed from past stock market experience becomes a vital part of an investor’s toolkit*

Comment: In some circles one might use "kit".

Answer (score 6):

This is more suitable for computing than sewing, but consider *utilities*, which (as noted in the link below) is derived from *utilis* (useful).

Please excuse the self-referential definition.

> **Utility** *noun*
>   3 Computing A utility program: a handy utility for converting one graphics file type to another
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/utility)

Your sample sentences would then be:

- Don’t forget to bring the needed *utilities* with you” (addressing to a service engineer); and
- “I put all my *utilities* into this folder on Google Drive”.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of only one noun that fits here nicely:

> Don’t forget to bring the (adjective, if needed) essentials with you.

You may want to put an appropriate adjective before the word i.e. "programming essentials"

> -Essential
>
> a basic, indispensable, or necessary element; chief point:

Comment: "needed essentials" seems tautological ?

Comment: ^That is a fair point. "Don’t forget to bring the needed programming essentials with you." would indeed sound pretty weird. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Actually, "necessary shit" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: "the necessities" is also often used this way. Both phrases show up often in articles on packing, organizing, etc. in a variety of contexts.

Answer (score 5):

**Supplies** can include components that are stocked in the expectation that they will frequently be used. For example, a mold manufacturer may stock several sizes of socket-head cap screws, or an electronics manufacturer may expect to keep 10K ohm resistors in stock. That would contrast with parts that are special to a particular project or job.

It would also include non-components that are consumed in the work, such as solvents, greases, solders and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Everything relevant to the situation, time, person, place, party, etc., can and is now referred to unreservedly as ***stuff*** by concerned parties. The word ***stuff*** applies in every situation given here (8) thus far.

***Stuff*** can compose and comprise the materials, processes, tools, and consumables whether they be traditional or state-of-the-art.

In addition, one of the highest compliments that can be bestowed by one upon another is paid to those who really know their ***stuff***.

Comment: @HotLicks a slightly deodorized version of your observation in comments.

Answer (score 3):

**tools**

[Oxford learner's dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/tool_1)

> a thing that helps you to do your job or to achieve something

**utensils**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/utensil)

> 2. any instrument, vessel, or tool serving a useful purpose

**implements**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/implement?s=t)

> 1. any article used in some activity, especially an instrument, tool, or utensil

**apparatuses**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/apparatus)

> 1. a group or combination of instruments, machinery, tools, materials, etc., having a particular function or intended for a specific use

Answer (score 3):

**gear**

*“Don’t forget to bring the **repair gear** with you.”

“I put all my **troubleshooting gear** into this folder on Google Drive”*

> [MASS NOUN, USUALLY WITH MODIFIER] Equipment or apparatus that is used for a particular purpose:  e.g. *'camping gear'*
>   [...]
>   *A few weeks after they'd gone missing, some of their **personal dive gear** washed up on a beach 75 miles from the dive site.*
>   *They caught five poachers, equipped with **modern rappelling gear**, in possession of six bags of bird nests.*
>   — [OD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gear)

Probably this one sounds better for craftsman/service-engineer examples than the other scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

One might (modestly) refer to his useful components as ***bits and bobs***.

> I put all my *bits and bobs* into a folder on Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use *bits and pieces*, or *odds and ends* to indicate things that whilst useful, are not essential to the process in question.

Or maybe *gubbins*, though I'm not sure how widespread the term is.